# The type parameter cannot be used with type arguments

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I wanted to code a helper method in Unit test project, which will initialize the presenter set the views instance to it and set the presenter state.

It threw me the exception:

> the type parameter cannot be used with type arguments

Code:

```
public static **TPresenter<TView>** Initialize<TPresenter,TView>()
    where TPresenter: BasePresenter<TView>, new()
    where TView : new()
{
}
```

After couple of minutes I found the issue was with my return type `TPresenter<Tview>`

I read few posts which didn't clearly explain Why I'm not be able to say `T1<T2>`

I was forced to make the presenter assignment through reference parameter. Any explanations are welcome!

Comment: Why not just return `TPresenter`?  It is already constrained to a type that forces specialization to `TView` (via `BasePresenter<>`).

Comment: was jus hoping to avoid a cast at the caller side! assuming i could achieve T1<T2>! though i could have settled with Presenter return type initially wasnt really convinced why T1<T2> with all the where conditions mentioned cant help compile time validation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Basically there's no way of saying that a type parameter is *itself* a generic type with a particular number of type parameters - which you need to be able to do in order to make `TPresenter<TView>` make sense.

It's not clear what you mean by making it work via a reference parameter - whatever type you used for that ref parameter should be fine as a return type too. My guess is that it was just of type `TPresenter`, not `TPresenter<TView>`.

Comment: @ioWint: Right, so just make that the return type.

Comment: yeah i could, just thought to avoid an explicit cast at the caller side. never bothered so far with a T1<T2>, theoretically was hoping if all the where conditions are given it should be good!

Comment: Just to be clear, even with a `where` statement restricting the type of some `T` to a generic type only (e.g., `where T : ICollection<U>`), the compiler has insufficient information to do something like `T<U> someParameter`, correct? Just out of curiosity, why is that? Some kind of circular reference workaround?

Comment: @jrh: That constraint doesn't mean that T is a generic type. For example, `class StringList : ICollection<string>` would allow T=StringList and U=string.

Comment: @JonSkeet Good point. I forgot about cases where types inherit from a specific `T` instead of having a derived generic class (e.g., something like `class MyCollection<T> : ICollection<T>`). Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a `TPresenter<TView>` it is meaningless. TPresenter is just a placeholder, until it is constrained by the where it could be anything, e.g. there is no `int<tview>` so you can't have that.  Once you add the constraint it means it has to be a `BasePresenter<TView>` or some derived type so it will always be a `Something<TView>` so again `TPresenter<TView>` is meaningless.

Comment: i get that i could mislead int<TView> but i do specify my constraints that TPresenter is of BasePresenter<TInterface> and TInterface is class. will this not be enough to ensure things are fine @ compile time?

Comment: The point is the the constraint says that TPresenter must be BasePresenter<TView> or something derived from it so your return type is just TPresenter

Answer (score 0):

This is an old one, but I hit it too. In the Class definition, just use the single type, then multiple types where you use it. E.g:

```
public class Template1<T>{}

void SomeFunc()
{
    <Template1<SomeClass1,SomeClass2>> someValue = new <Template1<SomeClass1,SomeClass2>>()
}

//or even:
void SomeOtherFunc<U,V>()
{
    <Template1<U,V>> someValue = new <Template1<U,V>>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting similar error in my code. `@Jon Skeet` correctly points to the right direction. The return type is already generic, as specified by `TPresenter : BasePresenter<TView>`. So we can simply use it as `TPresenter` instead of `TPresenter<TView>`.

```
public class BasePresenter<T>
{

}

public class Demo
{
    public static TPresenter Initialize<TPresenter, TView>() where TPresenter: BasePresenter<TView>, new()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Small addition, I came here because i was trying to write an extension method;

```cs
        public static T AutoJoinGroup<T, TD>(this T<TD> groupHubClientBase, string groupName)
            where T : GroupHubClientBase<TD>
        {
...
        }
```

As you can see, I tried to use `T<TD>` which is incorrect, you can just use `T`